# Where is MSVS 2015 store settings?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Where is MSVS 2015 store settings?
Infinite restoration damaged options.

---

- not help
  uninstall MSVS2015
  delete remainder after uninstall
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
  search in c:\Users\ and delete
  *.vssettings
  *.config
  studio (for VisualStudio)
  14 (14.0)
  c:\users*\documents\visual studio 2015\settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings
  c:\Users*\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\
  c:\Users*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\
  c:\Users*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\
  c:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\
  c:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
  c:\Users*\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2015\
  c:\Users\All Users\regid.1991-06.com.microsoft\regid.1991-06.com.microsoft Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.swidtag
  c:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\
  c:\ProgramData\Microsoft Visual Studio\14.0\
  Create new windows user, without password, with administrative rights of Administrators.
  Install MSVS2015.
  Tools->Options saved even after that.
  Where saved Tools->Options?
  Many options without changes, even font is same.

  ---

MSVS 2015 not work rebuild project on start project, not work auto rebuild.
Windows 10
MSVS2015, press green triangle (Local Windows Debugger), it will start previous *.exe instead make new from new code.
Message (This project is out of date Would you like to build it) appears only once.
Seems Code Analysis work once too.
Old project starts with syntax errors in new project.
Cause creating wrong old *.exe, not new.
Difficult to delete modification file of MSVS2015, which not delete even after uninstall.

---

May help, but not appropriate.
Manually delete after each creation.
*\ConsoleApplication*\Release\ConsoleApplication*.pdb
Or manually clean, rebuild project each time.
Or Build->Batch Build.
Or reinstall windows, take too much time.
Install on fresh W10 work, but not appropriate.

---

- not help
  repair from installation disk
  vs_enterprise.exe

  ---
- not help
  Devenv.exe /ResetSettings "c:\Users*\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings"

  ---
- not help
  Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run
  Diagnostic instead of Minimal
  Seems any changes in Build and Run without effect.
- not help
  Present. Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run.
  Always build.
  Prompt to launch.
  Absent. For new solutions use the currently selected project at the startup project.
  Output. Minimal. Log file. Minimal.
- not help
  Build -> Configuration Manager -> [Build] present

  ---
- not help
  Replace c:\users*\documents\visual studio 2015\settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings with file from working MSVS2015 from other OS W10

  ---
- not help
  Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset all settings->without save->Visual C++
  choose Visual C++, then back to initial.
  Or Reset all modification.

  ---
- not help
  change in CurrentSettings.vssettings
  [PropertyValue name="NOENCRebuild"]0[/PropertyValue]
  to
  [PropertyValue name="NOENCRebuild"]1[/PropertyValue]

  ---
- not help
  istead of
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
  create by guest user, install MSVS2015 in
  c:\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
  Programming Languages->Visual C++

  ---
- not help
  Tools->Import and Export Settings
  Import selected environment settings->General->All->Finish

  ---
- not help
  if delete C:\Users*\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Settings
  The automatically saved settings file 'c:\users*\documents\visual studio 2015\settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings' cannot be found. You can change this file on the 'Import and Export Settings' Tools Options page. The IDE will use your most recent settings for this session.

  ---
- not help
  Is there conflict between MSVS2015 and other programs, SDK, redistributables?
  Seems, reinstall windows, or work on other computer easier than find solution, so.
  Uninstall MSVS2015.
  Uninstall many useful and not very programs via Control Panel.
  Reinstall MSVS2015.

  ---

Perhaps it hide in windows registry or in packed, changed form?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:C++]?

Comment: Trying write C++ program

Comment: That is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: If you help me find solution without C++, that is ok.